# mysql activity feed of people you follow (likes, comments, etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, android-activity, feed

Some background:

I'm developing kind of social network. 
There is DB with next tables:

```
users(user_id, user_name, password, etc.)
posts(post_id, user_id, post_text, post_data, etc.)
followings(relationship_id, follower_id, following_id, added_date_time)
likes(like_id, user_id, post_id, added_date_time)
comments(comment_id, user_id, post_id, comment_text, added_date_time)
```

The question is:

How can I implement query which would fetch information about what my followings(people I follow) have did recently (e.g. someone liked/commented something) and order this array of info by date_time?

Can I make it using one query? Or I'll have to make multiple queries and handle all this stuff in PHP by myself?

What is the best approach?

Comment: As per my suggestion you should create different queries and all the results are combined and send as JSON / XML will be good for you.

e.g.

`JSON_OBJ = [users:{user_id: 1},{user_id: 2}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can normalize the output in a select union like this one

```
SELECT t.type, t.user_id, u.user_name, t.type_id, t.post_id, t.text, t.added_date_time 
  FROM (
  SELECT 'posts' as type, p.user_id, p.post_id as type_id, p.post_id, post_text as text, p.added_date_time
    FROM posts p  
    JOIN followings f ON (f.following_id = p.user_id) 
   WHERE f.follower_id = @user
   UNION
  SELECT 'comments' as type, c.user_id, c.comment_id as type_id, c.post_id, comment_text as text, c.added_date_time
    FROM comments c
    JOIN followings f ON (f.following.id = c.user_id)
   WHERE f.follower_id = @user
   UNION
  SELECT 'likes' as type, l.user_id, l.like_id as type_id, l.post_id, post_text as text, l.added_date_time
    FROM likes l
    JOIN followings f ON (f.following.id = c.user_id)
    JOIN posts p ON (l.post_id = p.post_id)
   WHERE f.follower_id = @user
  ) as t 
JOIN users u ON (t.user_id = u.user_id) 
ORDER BY added_date_time DESC;
```

So you can get all the data in only one query.

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: Man, I've used your idea and it worked like a charm!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to seperate at least the queries for likes and comments, since the result set is different.

Otherwise your query would look e.g. like:

```
SELECT comment_id,comment_text,added_date_time FROM comments WHERE user_id IN (SELECT following_id FROM followings WHERE follower_id={{USER_ID_FROM_USER}}) ORDER BY added_date_time
```

This will get you the comments from people which are followed by {{USER_ID_FROM_USER}} ordered by date.